# How can I get ldap-sync for postgres to grant the AD Group role to its group-members?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-13

We are using ldap-sync (github.com/larskanis/pg-ldap-sync) to bring members of an AD Group into a postgres cluster as user-roles however the user role that is based on the AD Group is not being granted to the user role based on the AD Account that is a member of that group. How can we achieve this?

Comment: What is ldap-sync?  Is that specific product?  Do you have a link to it?

Comment: @jjanes https://github.com/larskanis/pg-ldap-sync